# keypress event not capturing target value in ES6

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6

I've been refactoring a small javascript project to ES6 and noticed that an the `keypress` event listener that is applied to a text input is not including the pressed character in the target value for the event. This behaviour can be seen in this fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/yayinalato/edit?js,console,output

```
$input = document.querySelector('.input')

$input.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

The `keyup` event works but this also captures non-text input keypresses like arrow keys etc which is undesirable for this. This is why I'm confused as to why the `keypress` event does not work as I was under the impression a keyup had to happen for a keypress.

How can I get the value of the target to include the key pressed from this event? An explanation of how these events are captured would be helpful.

Comment: the jsbin is working ?

Comment: no, you will see the logged output does not include the key pressed that fired the event

Comment: eh, yes it does. maybe you have ES6 support switched off?

Comment: I am compiling the ES6 with babel, as is the JSbin. I am not seeing this behaviour. So you type a character and its immediately logged?

Comment: Why are you using `keypress` instead of `input` if you have an `<input>` form element?

Comment: _"I was under the impression a keyup had to happen for a keypress"_ keydown -> keypress -> update control -> keyup

Answer (score 0):

e.target refers to the element that triggered the event, which is the input field. If you check e.target.value you get the value of the input field at the moment the keypress event is fired. This happens before the text is actually entered in the field.

What you need to do is simply use e.keyCode to check which key is pressed.

```
$input.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
  console.log("keypressed " + e.charCode);
})
```

Also note that `(e)=>` only works in browsers that support ES6, or you have to use Babel to convert back to ES5

Comment: I am using babel to convert back to es5

Comment: This fiddle works? http://jsbin.com/qayoyavuwe/1/edit?js,console,output